# My linux-firmware just updated. What signs of trouble should I watch for as a user?

Tags: updates

It was just a normal update through Software updater, which notified me that the update was available, and I clicked Install, waited for it to finish, and then rebooted just to be on the safe side. I don't have any unstable repositories enabled, just the standard Ubuntu repositories plus source code, partners, and partners source code.

I'm familiar with the basics of Linux and have some skill on the command line but am not a sysadmin or a bash scripter. I do some light programming but nothing that touches the operating system or installed repository packages. I've got nothing installed from source. I've got a few Python3 libraries installed through pip3, and sometimes use them.

tl;dr what should a guy like me be attentive to that might be a sign his system broke, without being paranoid about it or taking too much time away from my normal computer use?

Ubuntu 16.04.3 64-bit.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When your system is in trouble, you get Error messages and alerts. When it's broken, you'll get those messages every day. You will surely know. Look through a few threads here and you will see what real *broken* looks like. Judging by the habits you describe, you may see many years before encountering problems.

Comment: I'm talking about smaller, subtle stuff I wouldn't notice unless I paid attention to it. The break doesn't have to be big to be a break.

Comment: Oh, then just check your /var/log/syslog on occasion, looking for Warnings before they grow into Errors.

Comment: lol if its not effecting you ... its not broke :D ... you will always have broken parts in your system ... that's linux :D (actually any OS)  ... you fix it when it starts causing you issues in what you do ... I have several errors that  pop ups ... no one knows how to solve them .. they don't cause me any issues .. so I ignore them

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll read up some more on linux-firmware and leave it at that.

Comment: as user535733 mentioned .. checking /var/log/syslog will show you some issues if you have any .. if you get errors and warnings there you can google them and see if there is a fix or .... just useless or outdated warnings that can be ignored

Comment: Updates of firmware?! Kernel yes. Drivers sure. Software sure. But firmware? I really doubt Linux/Ubuntu updates firmware. That's up to the manufacturer of the hardware and they hardly care about informing you.

Comment: @Rinzwind There exists in deed a package named `linux-firmware` which is installed by default, at least in my system (UbuntuStudio 16.04.3).

Comment: Sure but when that is changed we get a new *kernel*.

Comment: @Rinzwind No, `linux-firmware` is not a kernel package.

Comment: I agree with @fkraiem. On 2018-01-25, I received `linux-firmware:amd64 (1.157.14, 1.157.15)` and today, I got a kernel upgrade.